# android : security provider to protect against SSL exploits

Tags: android, security

I am adding check for device security provider is updated to avoid security vulnerabilities.
I have added `ProviderInstaller.installIfNeededAsync(this, this)` in my MainActivity and on all devices tested I see that onProviderInstalled() callback is getting executed.

I wanted test the failure case. For that I want to know what exactly is installIfNeededAsync checking. Is it comparing if device has the latest/ particular version of google play?
From code I understood it only checks if it has some package. I could be wrong.

Also How I can test the installFailed scenario

Answer (score 2):

It's checking the TLS providers installed and working inserting latest GMS one at the top. To really test this you'd need a vulnerable server and to compare what happens with and without some installing the GMS provider. https://github.com/google/nogotofail might be helpful